# Close child window and open link in a framed page

Tags: javascript

Trying to open a link in a framed page and close the child window. The link bellow is in a child window and when I click it opens the link in the framed page, but did not close the child window

```
<a target="Resultado" href="?Tela=1"
onClick="javascript:return confirm('TryMe');window.close();">
```

I have used a code like this to close the window... but couldn't get it to work with the above code.

```
<a href="javascript:window.opener='Resultado';window.close();">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a target="Resultado" href="?Tela=1" onclick="clickHandler(event, this);">Link</a>
```

And declare this:

```
function clickHandler(e, el) {
    var choice = confirm('TryMe');
    if (!choice) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    window.close();
}
```

I wasn't sure of your original use of `window.close()` since it came after the `return` and would never execute, so it's up to you to move it to where you want.

Comment: Thanks Ian. The `window.close()` in the first example was me trying to make it work. Can I have a inline code to close the window like the second example instead of using a function? Hope you do not understand as I am not ignoring the solution you gave me... I am just looking for an inline code... thanks again

Comment: @Khrys Sorry I hadn't responded in so long. My point in using this setup is because it's easier to maintain, and I wasn't exactly sure what you wanted to actually happen. So for now, can you let me know if the actual behavior is achieved with the function I provided? If so, I can condense it to do the same as inline code. If you can explain what you want, and provide more of your HTML structure, I might be able to help

Comment: @Khrys No problem at all, as long as you got a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Create another webpage on your webserver & use that as the Custom URL thankyou page for your form.

In that new webpage have just one line of code.

```
<body onload="javascript:window.opener.childClosed();window.close();">
```

--

That code will call a javascript function in the parent window and then close the child popup; you can then use that javascript function to do a redirect on your parent page.

I am not to sure where the URL of your 'Thank you for requesting...' page is, but here is some javascript to redirect to google on your parent page after the form is submitted.

function childClosed() {

    window.location = "http://www.google.com/"

  }

You can put that script before your closing `<body>` tag.

--

Hopefully I have understood your query OK, let me know if you have any questions or need any clarification on this possible solution.

-

I have made a very basic clone of your webpage & form here if you want to test out the functionality, 'Factoring Question?' is the link that contains this code.

Comment: <body onload="javascript:window.opener.childClosed();window.close();">